# props from father component is undefined in child although it work correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I pass data from father component to child and in child display it in view. Everything is working fine but when I go to consol I found out that I have issue occure there although code is working just fine and displayed data is what I expected.

Father component:

```
<article-header :article="articles"></article-header>
```

this line is in `<template>` tags. Article variable is value gathered in API backend http request.

In child component which is `<article-header>` I use this data like so:

```
<template>
<p>{{ article[0].title }}</p>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        props:['article']
    }

</script>
```

And it is working fine it show me my title from database exacly like I want but it also give error in browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"
>
> found in
>    --->  at src\components\no_related\article\elements\articleHeader.vue
>          at src\components\no_related\article\article.vue
>            at src\App.vue

Anyone know what could cause such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is rendering your component before your backend http request has finished, i.e. your article is still undefined. That's what's causing the entry in the console.

Once your http request has finished, Vue updates the component with the now existing data. That's what you see in the browser.

Comment: What can I do to fix it? I mean it's working but I also don't want to have any errors in my console. Can I somehow delay reading props in child component? Or maybe should I just do http request inside child? Second one feel silly because I would need to do exactly same request in both children.

Comment: Please provide actual solution to this behavior because right now you only explained why this happens. Then I will accept this answer.

Comment: You could initialize your articles with a place-holder object, a dummy that just has an empty title. Once your http request has finished, you replace the dummy with the actual data.

Comment: If i understand correctly I already have tried to do something like this, I create empty array named article in data function `data() {
            return {
                article: []
            }
        },` but then error is `The data property "article" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.`

Comment: After all I just used v-if to verify if article already exist. I think this solution is efficient enough as well, isn't it?